# how to get language of operating system is double byte in delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to detect the language of operating system is double byte or not.
to get the language i am using GetLocaleInfo function of windows. But i want to detect is language double byte or not. I can do this with taking name of language and decide is it double byte or not (i.e if language is Japanese then its double byte) but is there any other way to directly get is operating system double byte language or not.

code i am using to get language:

```
procedure GetLanguage();
    var
    Buffer : PChar; 
     Size : integer;
    begin
      Size := GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, nil, 0);
      GetMem(Buffer, Size);
      try
        GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, Buffer, Size);
        Writeln(Buffer);
      finally
        FreeMem(Buffer);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: `GetCPInfoEx(CP_ACP, 0, CpInfo);` `NotSingleByte := CpInfo.MaxCharSize > 1`. Or `TEncoding.GetEncoding(CP_ACP).IsSingleByte`. I think it depends on what you mean by *language of operating system*.

Comment: It's unclear, what *"double byte"* means to you. Windows uses UTF-16 as its character encoding. Every code point is thus encoded in 2 or 4 bytes. It's also unclear why you need to know (whatever it is). What are you going to do with that information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you call "double byte"? Do you mean that when using AnsiString, it may have characters encoded with two AnsiChar?

Use the following code:

```
FarEast := GetSystemMetrics(SM_DBCSENABLED) <> 0;
```

Edited, since `SysLocale.FarEast` is forced to true on Unicode Delphi.

Comment: OS support double byte character but my question is about the language of OS is Japanese then its double byte character language and if language is English then it's not double byte character language. your answer gives me is user32.dll support double byte character or not. I debug with your ans. but value of  SysLocale.FarEast is true in both cases of Japanese  and English O.S.(operating system) which is because it's do support DBCS. @Arnaud

Comment: you are right  in newest Delphi there is:
{$IF DEFINED(UNICODE)}
  SysLocale.FarEast := True;
{$ELSE}
  SysLocale.FarEast := GetSystemMetrics(SM_DBCSENABLED) <> 0;
{$ENDIF}
Which IMHO is not correct, as used for Ansi*() functions. So I edited my answer, which was correct on older Delphi. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: SM_DBCSENABLED
Nonzero if User32.dll supports DBCS; otherwise, 0. It is working, thank you @Arnaud. one question is  will it work for 64 bit OS too or do we need to make changes?